# Autohotkey and Vim are they compatible?

Tags: vim, scripting, autohotkey

I always have problems to let Autohotkey scripts work with Vim.

p.e.

```
^g:: 
Send, ^c
MsgBox hi
return
```

doesn't work in Vim if I select a text and use the shortcut.
(same problem when I change the shortcut).

What did I wrong? 
Other people have the same compatibility problems between Autohotkey and Vim?

Comment: I don't know autohotkey, what do you want to do with vim? can't vim build-in mapping mechanism meet your needs?

Comment: Autohotkey is a scripting language. You can automate a lot of things in your pc using it. It is global and not dependent only to vim. A simple example is to copy a text wherever and use it with the help of autohotkey in another software or within a website but there are a lot more things you can do with it (moving applications on the screen p.e.)

Comment: @Reman, I was hoping it would work if both the AHK script and Gvim are opened as administrator. But, even that is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

what kind of vim are you using? one in a terminal or gVim? Short answer is that autohotkey works with vim. From how I read, you want to copy the text with <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>. Try that on your vim, that is not the command you use to copy. If you selected the text in vim's visual mode, then <kbd>y</kbd> is the key you are looking for and if you want to remap to <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd>, then the command to do it is pasting the following line in your .vimrc file in your home directory :

```
xmap <C-c> y
```

If you are using a terminal (mintty) or gVim and you selected the text with your mouse, the command to copy is <kbd>ctrl-insert</kbd>. I have a feeling this is what you are looking for.

```
^c::Send {Ctrl down}{Insert}{Ctrl Up}
^v::Send {Shift down}{Insert}{Shift Up}
```

paste can be done with <kbd>shift-insert</kbd>, as noted in the second line. If you want this behavior to work specifically under a certain program, you can use the following lines instead:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class mintty
    ^+v::Send {Shift down}{Insert}{Shift Up}
    ^+c::Send {Ctrl down}{Insert}{Ctrl Up}
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Yes you're right; Autohotkey works with Vim. I had to elevate my autohotkey scripts to administrator to let it work in a vim window with admin rights. :)